# Why can't I edit these values outside the scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I am working on a ray tracer where I need to be able to change certain variables based on input on runtime. I have values such as `CamDir` and `CamPos` that need to be changed over runtime but keep reverting back to their default values. I think there's an issue with storing the variables back into the `Renderer` struct. It would make sense, as I'm new to programming and suck at understanding borrowing and ownership stuff. Here I'll include my code on GitHub, as well as a simpler example that somewhat faithfully recreates the situation I'm dealing with. I've been struggling with this issue for quite a while, so I'd appreciate help trying to fix my terrible code.

GitHub: https://github.com/KGL8/RayTracingPaper/tree/working_snapshot

Simplified Code Example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct feed {
    foodId: i32,
    healthy: bool
}

impl feed {
    pub fn new(foodId: i32) -> feed {
        feed {
            foodId: foodId,
            healthy: true
        }
    }
    
    pub fn newValues(mut self) {
        self.healthy = false;
        self.foodId = 234567645;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct animal {
    animalType: i32, // 0 = dog, 1 = cat
    foodType: feed,
    joy: i32         // 0% -> 100%
}

impl animal {
    pub fn new(animalType: i32, foodType: feed) -> animal {
        animal {
            animalType: animalType,
            foodType: foodType,
            joy: 50
        }
    }
    
    pub fn changePetFood(self) {
        self.foodType.newValues();
    }
}

pub fn walk(mut a: animal) {
    a.changePetFood();
    a.joy = 100;
}

fn main() {
    let food = feed::new(264369);
    let doggy = animal::new(0,food);
    
    println!("{:?}",doggy); 
    walk(doggy);
    println!("{:?}",doggy);
}
```

I've tried a whole combination of mutability, referencing, and passing as parameters, but nothing seems to work out...

Here is a tree that attempts to explain the structure I've set up for my code:

Main.rs -> [1] App.rs -> Renderer.rs -> Camera.rs -> App.rs -> Renderer.rs -> [Loop back to [1]]

Comment: Not related to your question, which others have answered, but `animalType: i32, // 0 = dog, 1 = cat` should really be an `enum`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the distinction between a *value* and a *reference*.

In Rust, when you pass a value as a parameter to a function, this **moves** the value (except for the basic primitive types and some variations around that, which are simply copied because it costs almost nothing).
This means that now the value is not anymore in its initial location but in the parameter of the function (this is simplified, but the main idea is here): the function has **consumed** the value which is not available anymore in its initial location.
For example, calling `walk(doggy)` consumes `doggy` and you cannot display it after this call.

Instead, you should pass a **reference** to `doggy` in order to leave it in place but interact with it anyway.
Because your intention is to mutate `doggy`, you have to pass a **mutable** (exclusive) reference: `walk(&mut doggy)` but `duggy` must have been declared as mutable to allow that (`let mut doggy = ...`).

Of course, the parameter of `walk()` must be changed to `a: &mut Animal`.

If you are OK with this till this point, then you should be able to follow the same way for the other errors (they are similar).
You just have to known that `self` is a shortcut for `self: Self`, `&self` is a shortcut for `self: &Self` and `&mut self` is a shortcut for `self: &mut Self`, where `Self` represents the considered type for the implementation (`Feed`, `Animal`...)

As a side note, you should consider the compiler warnings about the naming conventions for the types, variables, functions...
And as stated in a comment, the integer `animal_type` can be replaced by an `enum` representing only the expected animals.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Feed {
    food_id: i32,
    healthy: bool,
}

impl Feed {
    pub fn new(food_id: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            food_id,
            healthy: true,
        }
    }

    pub fn new_values(&mut self) {
        self.healthy = false;
        self.food_id = 234567645;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum AnimalType {
    Dog,
    Cat,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Animal {
    animal_type: AnimalType,
    food_type: Feed,
    joy: i32, // 0% -> 100%
}

impl Animal {
    pub fn new(
        animal_type: AnimalType,
        food_type: Feed,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            animal_type,
            food_type,
            joy: 50,
        }
    }

    pub fn change_pet_food(&mut self) {
        self.food_type.new_values();
    }
}

pub fn walk(a: &mut Animal) {
    a.change_pet_food();
    a.joy = 100;
}

fn main() {
    let food = Feed::new(264369);
    let mut doggy = Animal::new(AnimalType::Dog, food);

    println!("{:?}", doggy);
    walk(&mut doggy);
    println!("{:?}", doggy);
}
/*
Animal { animal_type: Dog, food_type: Feed { food_id: 264369, healthy: true }, joy: 50 }
Animal { animal_type: Dog, food_type: Feed { food_id: 234567645, healthy: false }, joy: 100 }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on this function.

```rs
pub fn newValues(mut self) {
    self.healthy = false;
    self.foodId = 234567645;
}
```

This function does basically nothing. It moves `self` into the function, changes it, and then drops it. It has no way for this information to leave the function.

If you want to be able to observe these values after you change them, you need to either return `self`...

```
pub fn newValues(mut self) -> Self {
    self.healthy = false;
    self.foodId = 234567645;
    self
}
```

... or you need to take a mutable reference to self.

```rs
pub fn newValues(&mut self) {
    self.healthy = false;
    self.foodId = 234567645;
}
```

Note that `&mut self` in the argument list is special syntax that only works with `self`, and is the same as `self: &mut Self`. When you apply this to `walk`, it will look like this.

```rs
pub fn walk(a: &mut animal) {
    a.changePetFood();
    a.joy = 100;
}
```

These changes are necessary to make your example compile, but your full project looks to be using [`Copy` types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy). When you take a copy type by value, such as with `fn newValues(mut self)`, it copies the value into the function instead of moving it. This means the original value will still be valid, but it won't see the changes you make inside the function, since that's being done to a copy.

Your full example fixed looks like this.

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct feed {
    foodId: i32,
    healthy: bool,
}

impl feed {
    pub fn new(foodId: i32) -> feed {
        feed {
            foodId: foodId,
            healthy: true,
        }
    }

    pub fn newValues(&mut self) {
        self.healthy = false;
        self.foodId = 234567645;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct animal {
    animalType: i32, // 0 = dog, 1 = cat
    foodType: feed,
    joy: i32, // 0% -> 100%
}

impl animal {
    pub fn new(animalType: i32, foodType: feed) -> animal {
        animal {
            animalType: animalType,
            foodType: foodType,
            joy: 50,
        }
    }

    pub fn changePetFood(&mut self) {
        self.foodType.newValues();
    }
}

pub fn walk(a: &mut animal) {
    a.changePetFood();
    a.joy = 100;
}

fn main() {
    let food = feed::new(264369);
    let mut doggy = animal::new(0, food);

    println!("{:?}", doggy);
    walk(&mut doggy);
    println!("{:?}", doggy);
}
```

My advice would be to remove `Copy` from your types, then either explicitly call `clone()` or pass references wherever you get errors, and change your function signatures to match.